# Getting "Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser" on login page

Tags: login, migration, cookies

I've got a WP installation at `server-a.example.com` (*serverA*) and I want to duplicate it on a different server which is `server-b.example.com` (*serverB*).

My steps are:

1. Copy database
2. Copy files

   - No need to edit `wp-config.php` (database details are just the same, localhost same user same password)
3. Replace *serverA* domain with *serverB* into the database using [this tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

The *serverB* clone seems to work, but I experience two problems:

1. I cannot login into `wp-admin` of *serverB* because I receive the error

   > Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser`
2. WordPress changes the active theme

Now I'd like to understand the reason behind problem #2, but let that alone for the time being, I've only reported it as it might be a hint for you to spot the real problem.

The question is how do I login? Needless to say, my browser does support cookies and I've tried with different browsers too. I've tried resetting the administrator password via SQL (just in case), but it still blocks me out with the cookies message.

P.S. I'm not sure this question belongs here or serverfault or what else, please move it as needed.

EDIT:

This is not a duplicate because the accepted answer for [the other existing question](/questions/166181) does not hold in my case: there's no Varnish/NGINX/Squid/other reverse proxy on my servers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't log in: “ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.”](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166181/cant-log-in-error-cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser-you)

Comment: Try deleting your login cookie from the original location

Comment: Fair enough. Collected a few ideas and added them as an answer. Also, do you use any caching plugins?

Comment: @jdm2112 tried, it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @DaveRomsey yes, I do use W3TC. I've tried disabling it (by moving its folder out of the way) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Added some W3TC-specific notes to my answer. Removing the plugin is important, but there are some additional files that need to be removed too.

Comment: this is impossible to answer. turn off all plugins and check if it still happens, if it is then there is some setting (do you a have a security plugin going on?) that kills the cookies domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrangled up some things to check:

@otto via comment on this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166181/cant-log-in-error-cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser-you)

> Look at the login page's HTML source. Is there anything at all before
>   the initial DOCTYPE line? Even a blank line? If so, then you have some
>   piece of code creating output before the headers are made, in which
>   case this prevents it from setting cookies.

Some suggestions from [a highly relevant post with several additional ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941328/wordpress-admin-login-cookies-blocked-error-after-moving-servers) on Stack Overflow:

(I know you said that there's no need to change anything in the `wp-config.php` file, but references to the old domain could be present. Please verify for sure that this is not necessary.)

> Verify the URLs are correct for `siteurl` and `home` in the
>   `wp_options` table. These can be reset easily by adding the following
>   to `wp-config.php`:
>
> ```
> define('WP_HOME','http://your-domain.com');
> define('WP_SITEURL','http://your-domain.com');
> ```

Check `wp-config.php` for improperly set `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` constant.

```
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'yourdomain.com' );
```

If the W3 Total Cache plugin was/is in use, temporarily remove the plugin from the plugins directory and ensure that the following lines are commented out/removed from `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_CACHE', true);
define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "www.domain.com");
```

Then, remove the following files from the `wp-content` directory:

```
w3-total-cache-config.php 
object-cache.php 
advanced-cache.php
db.php
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I had already checked: no content before DOCTYPE and no wrong costants in wp-config.php.