# Site Cookie Error, Redirection and Blank Pages after Upgrade

Tags: updates

I've updated my site http://www.velo-classique.com/ to the newest version of WP. The theme and all the plugins are updated but I get the following errors:

- Cookie error when login.
- When I save, for example, Writting options in WP Dashboard it redirects to a blank page.
- The velo-classique.com don't redirect to www.velo-classique.com.

I've checked the database, the wp-config.php and many thing that I've read on the Internet and troubleshooting section of WordPress and nothing works.

What can it be?

Comment: WP core is exceptionally backwards compatible. What was the previous core version and did you update regularly? Loose guess is either core was modified or extensions in use are too old (/too bad) to handle upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are newlines being generated before your `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration, which you can see by viewing the source code of your site from your browser:

[image]

As Rarst suggested, there is probably some incompatible code that is causing this output to be generated. The extra [whitespace can cause the issues you've described](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238931/cookies-on-login-page#comment356102_238931).

There are many resources on this site and others about troubleshooting whitespace appearing before the doctype declaration.

Comment: Thank you. A plugin caused this error. But it is weird, it was updated and just deleted the files and reinstalled it again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this on your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'http://www.example.com/');
```

If it there, remove it.

Comment: I've already done it and nothing. Thanks for your suggestion.