# Cookies error during first time login attempt

Tags: login, cache, cookies

I have a custom login url and when i am trying to login for first time it displays error "ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser.".
Although It works second time. I have discussed this with hosting provider and they told me that custom url's are out of their scope. i have tried all ways on this thread but nothing seems to be working for me.

[Can't log in: "ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress."](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166181/cant-log-in-error-cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser-you)

Here is my htacccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^account-login/?$ /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^account-login/register/?$ /wp-login.php?action=register [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^account-login/lostpassword/?$ /wp-login.php?action=lostpassword [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: does it work with the normal standard URLs? What you're trying to do via htaccess is very unlikely to work, and not how it's normally done

Comment: I am using  
Protect WP-Admin plugin for custom admin url. Yes it works with wp-admin but not working with custom url.

Comment: It is important for me to use custom url because there are more then three thousand clients who have this url as admin url and i also used this plugin with few other sites and it works properly.

Comment: Nobody said a custom login URL was impossible, but the approach you've taken is very unlikely to work. Other approaches would work better. I recommend instead of debugging your specific approach, that you instead ask how to implement a custom login. You can get the result you want, just not this way

Comment: Ok thank you for your reply. I will try a different way now to implement custom login url.